# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded for file upload

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, timeout

I need to upload big files with a PHP script. I set max_upload_size and so on. I tried to upload a big file that took 30 minutes. Than I get:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded ... on line 1

My first line has a constant definition so it is impossibile that the script lose all exec time in that line.
Seems that the script excecution time get the elapsed time from the beginning of upload instead of the end... Am I right? I don't want to extend the normal execution time, I just want to let php count only its time and not the upload time. Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0):

crete a **php.ini** file write

max_execution_time = 0

save and upload your main dir

Comment: This remove the excecution timeout, but this is not an excecution problem.

Comment: You're still likely to hit webserver issues if you're uploading files that take that long to upload

Comment: probably safe_mode on in your server.